# What would "POSIX.1-2008 marks ftw() as obsolete" consequently mean?

Tags: c, posix, obsolete

Reading `man 3 ftw` I observe that "POSIX.1-2008 marks ftw() as obsolete".
Now I am concerned and want to be a "nice programmer" and maybe respect obsoleteness of `ftw()`. Still I struggle now with finding out what else I should use that is now "up-to-date" and in a matter of speaking what the replacement for `ftw()` is that made it obsolete.

If allowed I am especially interested in two sub questions.

1. Can I still use `ftw()`?
2. Is there a way to estimate the *risks* involved doing so?
3. What is the successor of `ftw()`

I hope for mercy if and am open for suggestion to improve the question, while still being happy to be helped and accepted given it is challenging and I tried well to compose the question.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, you should avoid using obsolete functions. For `ftw()`, the replacement is `nftw()`:

```
int nftw(const char *path, int (*fn)(const char *,
       const struct stat *, int, struct FTW *), int fd_limit, int flags);
```

From [Open Group](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/):

> The `ftw()` function may allocate dynamic storage during its operation. If `ftw()` is forcibly terminated, such as by `longjmp()` or `siglongjmp()` being executed by the function pointed to by `fn` or an interrupt routine, `ftw()` does not have a chance to free that storage, so it remains permanently allocated. A safe way to handle interrupts is to store the fact that an interrupt has occurred, and arrange to have the function pointed to by `fn` return a non-zero value at its next invocation.
>
> Applications should use the `nftw()` function instead of the obsolescent `ftw()` function.